# Android: rendering WebView off-screen at a specified display resolution

Tags: android, webview, webkit, rendering

Is there a way to render the WebView client to an off-screen buffer at a specified display resolution?

I did find some code to picture capture a WebView client and place it in a bitmap, but I do not want to convert the output to a bitmap, I'd just want to direct the WebView rendering overlays to a different location in memory and specify the display size.

Essentially I want to specify an off-screen frame buffer for WebView to write to.

thanks.

Comment: I sort of managed to get this working by offsetting the Window Manager layout x, y params to be outside the SurfaceFlinger frame buffer's "visible region". However, with this change it looks like the SurfaceFlinger Regions (transparent, visible) are all [0, 0, 0, 0]. On taking a bitmap snapshot, I have verified that the webpage is indeed getting loaded and rendered. Does this mean that HW acceleration via GPU graphics is disabled for off-screen rendering? I'm trying to understand how my page is getting rendered if SurfaceFlinger does not do anything to off-screen images.